# Batch: Odd problems using Spaces in Set /p input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have encountered a problem when entering spaces into a **Set /p** command in Batch. Here is a piece of code I have that will run your input as a command (basically CMD).

```
@echo off
:Set
set /p op="C:\Users\Bob\
if %op%==%op% goto Run
:Run
%op%
goto Set
```

Again this is a basic piece of my code, but when for example I enter

```
Net user
```

It will escape and close the window. what is the problem with the Set /P Command? TIA

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of the `set /p` command.

Comment: What's the purpose of an `if` clause that always evaluates to true??

Comment: Magoo answered your question below but if you want to make your pseudo prompt look more like the regular cmd prompt then change the code to this: `set /p "op=C:\Users\Bob\>"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing. Well, it's always a good idea to balance the quotes.

```
set /p op="C:\Users\Bob\"
```

Which will do precisely nothing to alleviate the problem.

```
set /p op=C:\Users\Bob\
```

would do the same thing. The quotes are not relevant

```
set /p "op=C:\Users\Bob\ "
set /p op="C:\Users\Bob\ "
```

Would show a space after the <kbd>\</kbd>

The second syntax is similar to the "safe" `set` syntax

```
set "op=C:\Users\Bob\ "
```

which would set the string between the <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> into the variable. The positioning of the quotes in this way ensures that trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned.

```
set op=C:\Users\Bob\ 
set "op=C:\Users\Bob\"
```

may actually do different things. The second would ensure that `C:\Users\Bob\` was assigned to `op`. The first - well, `op` would acquire `C:\Users\Bob\` **plus** any trailing spaces on the line (which are conveniently invisible when `type`d)

Your problem is that if your entry contains spaces,

```
if %op%==%op% goto Run
```

substitutes the value of `op`, then checks the result for valid syntax, so you get

```
if Net user==Net user goto Run
```

which is invalid syntax. The syntax of `if` is

> if *string* operator *string* dothis

so batch sees `user` where it expects an operator and shows a syntax error. If you've run this batch fby double-clicking, it will then close the `cmd` instance. This is why running batch from the prompt is preferred.

The solution is to `"enclose the strings in double-quotes"``

```
if "%op%"=="%op%" goto Run
```

becomes

```
if "Net user"=="Net user" goto Run
```

since batch sees a "series of strings separated by spaces" as a single quoted string.

btw - it's normal practice to avoid labels which are keywords (like `set`)